# Auto-run function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, custom-function

I've done a custom function in google script, **the curious thing it is that everytime I run another google script, this function appears to run again...**

I don't understand this... as a function, once you type it, the result should be static but it changes...

For example, when you use a non-custom function such as `sum`, it appears as a number and it doesn't change unless you decide to change the parameters...

More information, I'm not using any `onEdit()` code.

How can I run just once the custom function, for example, when I write it for the first time only in a cell?

My code is this one:

```
'/**
*
* 
* @customfunction
*/
function CreateID(row) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Relationships");
  var BI = BatchID(row);
  var data1 = ss.getRange('B:B').getValues();
  var data2 = ss.getRange('G:G').getValues();
  var Max = getMaxInColumn();
  var RoleName = SearchRoleName(row);
  var count = 0;

  for(var i = 0;i<row;i++){

     if(data1[i] == RoleName){

           if(data2[i] == Max){
           count = count +1;

           } // close 1.1.1 IF
         } // close 1.1 IF

  }
     Logger.log(count);

     if(count<BI){

     return Max;

     }else if(count>=BI){

     return Max+1;
     count = 0;
     Max=getMaxInColumn();
     }
    }'
```

And an example could be like this: 
Banana has a batch of 4 and Orange a batch of 3 
So I have two columns

```
Column 1 FRUIT   Column 2 ID 
Banana           1
Banana           1
Banana           1
Banana           1
Orange           2
Orange           2
Orange           2 
Banana           3
Orange           4
Banana           3
```

But when I run another function, even though in another project in the same spreadsheet, those numbers don't keep it values, cause I figure out that it runs again...

Thank you so much!

Comment: you need to include the code if you want people to help

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] so that we can help you to determine what the problem is.  Also take a look as [ask].  Perhaps you have not wrapped this function with a function () wrapper and so now it's a global function and yes it will run everytime you run any other script.  Please share your code.  Just putting a function in another file is not the same as wrapping it in a function() wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

All custom functions are in the global scope and hence, are loaded every time another function is called. Use a separate project for the custom function(s).

> File>New>Project

Comment: When I run other project in the same spreadsheet it still happens though... Thanks for helping, I added the code to the question description

Comment: @Laura Don't run other project. Other project should only be of custom functions. Nothing to run  there.